# Why is one particular page not being cached, and the others are? all have same caching headers

Tags: web-applications, browser, http, header

I've been reading a bunch on how caching of web pages is handled, I feel like I have a good grasp on everything, but I've encountered something I don't understand.

I'm testing a site and it sends the same caching headers on every HTTPS response.

```
Cache-Control: private
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: No-cache
```

Now as I understand it, responses should only be cached in the browser's cache because it's set to private. The application should use "max-age" instead of "Expires" as "Expires" is the old way to do things, but even still, it should see every cached response as stale because it is after that date. "Pragma" is an old HTTP 1.0 header, and I can't find information on how modern browsers handle that or if they just ignore it, but assuming they don't, then the browser should re-validate every request. If they do ignore it, then it should still re-validate every request because it sees its stored response as stale, correct?

Now here is why I'm confused. The actual behavior of the application is that you can use the back button on the browser to see the pages you've just visited, except for one. This is doubly confusing, because as I understand it, it should re-validate every request, but if it's because "Expires" is an old header and it's ignoring that, then it should just use the copy for all of them, so why is one particular page issuing a request, but not any of the others? I've gone over every header in both the request and response and there is nothing different about the headers for this page than the others. The only difference is this page has some sensitive userinfo in it, but how does the browser know that? This happens the same in both the current versions of Chrome and Firefox.

I didn't think browsers looked at the contents of the HTML when evaluating what gets cached and that it was just based on the response headers. Is this not the case? Can someone please help shed some light on what is happening and where my understanding is incorrect?

Comment: This question is off topic on Security SE.

Comment: @mentallurg apologies if that is the case, but How so? It relates to the behavior involved in security and isn't any different in nature than lots of other questions I found here while searching for the answer to my question. thanks

Comment: This is about caching behavior and not security. There *might* be a security implication as a result of this behavior, but what you've asked isn't actually about security.

Comment: You may want to check this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onpageshow.asp